# Determine through 3 argparse arguments

Tags: python, argparse

Firstly, I apologize if my title is misleading/ unclear as I am really not sure what is the best way to put it.

I have 3 optional arguments, which uses `action='store_true'`. Let's keep the argument flags to `-va, -vb, -vc`

```
var_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
if args.va:
    run_this_func(var_list[0])
if args.vb:
    run_this_func(var_list[1])
if args.vc:
    run_this_func(var_list[2])

if not args.higha and not args.highb and not args.highmem:
    for var in var_list:
    run_this_func(var)

if args.va and args.vb:
    run_this_func(var_list[:-1])
if args.vb and args.vc:
    run_this_func(var_list[1:])
if args.vc and args.va:
    run_this_func(var_list[0], var_list[2])
```

How can I code in more efficient way? The above method that I had utilized while it may work, seems more like a roundabout way to get things going...

Initially I am thinking of using tuple such that it will be something such as `input = (args.va, args.vb, args.vc)` so that it may return me eg. `(True, False, False)`... Not sure if that is ideal though.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use tuple too.

```
var_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
input = (args.va, args.vb, args.vc)
vars = [item for index, item in enumerate(var_list) if args_tuple[index]]
run_this_func(*vars)
```

Comment: A variant `[var for arg, var in zip(input, var_list) if arg]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a case where [`argparse.add_argument`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument)'s [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#nargs) and [`choices`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/argparse.html#choices) keywords can be used to get the list that you want (some subset of `[a,b,c]`) without having to filter based on multiple arguments.

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-v', choices=['a','b','c'], nargs='+')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

This says: create an optional argument `-v` that can take one or multiple values but each of those values must be one of `['a','b','c']`

Then you can pass it arguments from the command line like this (for example):

```
$ python my_file.py -v a c
```

which means that `args` will look like:  `Namespace(v=['a', 'c'])`
and `args.v` looks like `['a', 'c']` which is the list you were looking for (and without any filtering!)

You can then call your function as:

```
run_this_func(args.v)
```